# Css main file not load to browser

Tags: css, reactjs, nginx, production-environment

I have ubunto server working with nginx,
and after running `npm run build` in my react project, the build directory created with the path static/css/main.ca4e3296.chunk.css -> and that is the main css file of the project.

After ftp that build directory to the server, I checked this file and it transfered successfully, but on the production it's value is all the index.html content (I have no idea why).

I also copy paste all the static/css/main.ca4e3296.chunk.css file's content from the server to the browser and it's all the css worked again, which means **the problem here is that file that it's value changes from the server to the browser.**

Also, in the console, I get this message:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://bucard.co.il/static/css/main.ca4e3296.chunk.css".
```

By the way, this is my index.html page if it's couses the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bucard | Digital Business Card</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://bucard.co.il/" />

  <link rel="icon" id="favicon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant:wght@300&display=swap" as="style"
    onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" as="style"
    onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <meta name="title" content="Bucard | Digital Business Card" />
  <meta name="description"
    content="Bucard - Digital Card Website" />

  <!-- some analytics -->

  <meta property="og:locale" content="he_IL" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Bucard | Digital Business Card" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://bucard.co.il/favicon.ico" />
  <meta property="og:description"
    content="Bucard - Digital Card Website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://bucard.co.il/" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Bucard" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help please ? Or maybe it's Nginx problem?
**This problem causes only on production.**

edit: Just saw that removing GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false from .env file solved the problem, but the components are shown again. so that's temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the source code of your website, there's no CSS file named `main.ca4e3296.chunk.css` there.

It's probably the nginx routing settings that causes the redirect to your 404 page, which is fine.

You need to remember that with each new build the output files' names change, **and the main `index.html` file is updated as well to link to the new files**, so `main.ca4e3296.chunk.css` may have existed sometime in the past but not anymore. Currently, both `2.b42aba3b.chunk.css` and `main.a6f3b637.chunk.css` are responding as expected.

If I were you I'd read more about your bundler (most likely [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org))

Comment: hey, I do have this file in path bucard.co.il / static / css / main.ca4e3296.chunk.css (in the bottom, under all the components css files.
Before, I had only ```main.ca4e3296.chunk.css``` and ```2.b42aba3b.chunk.css``` file beacse I didn't generate source map.
The thing that issue my, is that it seriously happened with no reason, I didn't changed anything in my nginx configuration, and once I uploaded new updates for my website, build the project, ftp the files and restart the nginx, It suddenly didn't have the css code, and generate souce map solved that. 
What do you think ?